# Mapping complex joins in nHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have used nHibernate in my latest project and successfully mapped all the basic relationships where the values existed in either the primary table I was working with or through a simple relationship like a composite.

Where I am getting stuck is how does one go about mapping complex joins?

For example I have an entity called `Contact` each `contact` has your usual properties like Name, DOB, Phone.... But I also need it to have a property called `AccreditationList` which would be a `List<Accreditation>`.

Here is a sample of the Contact XML declaration.

```
<class name="Contact" table="Contact" lazy="true">

    <id name="ID" column="ContactID" type="guid">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>

    <property name="FirstName">
      <column name="FirstName" sql-type="nvarchar(500)" not-null="true" />
    </property>

    <property name="LastName">
      <column name="LastName" sql-type="nvarchar(500)" not-null="true" />
    </property>

    <bag name="AccreditationList" lazy="true">    
        //How do I express the relationship here? 
    </bag>

</class>
```

The `List<Accreditation>` can only be determined through a series of joins like this.

```
SELECT Accreditation.* FROM CourseEnrolment 
INNER JOIN Course ON Course.CourseID = CourseEnrolment.CourseID
INNER JOIN CourseType ON CourseType.CourseTypeID = Course.CourseTypeID
INNER JOIN Accreditation ON Accreditation.AccreditationID = CourseType.AccreditationID
WHERE CourseEnrolment.ContactID = :ContactID
```

Is the only way to accomplish this by manually invoking the SQL through nHibernate in code with `CreateSQLQuery` or can I express this relationship using something like named queries? What is the correct approach? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of options:

1. You can use `SqlSelect`, `SqlUpdate` etc.. to specify an arbitrary SQL statement for selecting / updating etc.. (a [mapping-by-code](http://notherdev.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/mapping-by-code-set-and-bag.html) example; I'm sure there's an XML equivalent)
2. You could map your SQL query to a `QueryOver` query, and use it to initialize your `Accreditation` collection.  Something along the lines of:

   `public Contact GetContact(int id)
       {
         var contact = _session.Get(id);
         contact.AccreditationList = _session.QueryOver<Accreditation>() /* your query here */;
         return contact;
       }`
   However!! this method has several drawbacks-

   - If you don't use the `GetContact` method, your collection won't be populated correctly.
   - It doesn't support Querying over Contact very easily (first you have to query for the contacts, and then you have to initialize each contact's accreditation list).
3. You could map the intermediate entity (`Course`) to your `Contact` entity (you can have it as a private member, if you don't want to expose them), and then your `AccreditationList` property would be

`public IEnumerable<Accreditaion> AccreditationList
    {
      get
      {
         return _courses.SelectMany(course => course.Accreditations);
      }
    }`

You wouldn't be able to manipulate the `Contact`'s `AccreditationList` directly, though.

The best solution would be to have something like `QueryOverSelect` option in the mapping, but AFAIK there isn't...
Personally I'd go with the 3rd option, since it seems the cleanest to me.